# Connect to Red5 server from another machine

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, red5

I am recording video using Flash and Red5 server and am doing it well,But when Red5 server is installed in another machine am not able to access it from my machine through LAN.
am using another machine IPAddress to connect. Example:"rtmp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/echo"
When i access in my local machine using "rtmp://localhost/echo" it works fine.
Can any one help me with this, Thanks In advance

Comment: Please check the Red5 settings to open the port and change the local host name to ip like 192.18.0.2(your ip). then restart the server and check it..

Comment: Doesn't Red5 use a very particular port? I think it's something like 5080.  So, maybe try xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5080/echo

Comment: Have you ensured that it's not a crossdomain.xml-related issue?

Comment: Thank you all, i  figured it out by using 
"rtmp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/echo" to connect to server and save the recorded video.
and "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:portnumber/" to connect to server and  retrieve video from server.

Where 
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx = Server ip address given to red5 server at   the time of installing.
port number = port number given to red5 server at the time of installing.

Answer (score 1):

You may uninstall the `red5` and reinstall it. When it ask you the server ip address type your machine's LAN adress (`192.168.2.***` or `10.0.0.*` whatever).

Comment: that popup is pretty damn confusing. I suspect it's actually the bind address, in which case use `0.0.0.0` for *all*. you can change this in the red5 config later anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The port maybe 1935 or 80, please check the file named like 'red.properties'.

You can find a property named 'rtmp.port' and try it.